# How do I change XML indentation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, xml, ide, intellij-idea

By default IntelliJ IDEA 7.0.4 seems to use 4 spaces for indentation in XML files.  The project I'm working on uses 2 spaces as indentation in all it's XML.  Is there a way to configure the indentation in IntelliJ's editor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure there is. This is all you need to do:

- Go to

```
File -> Settings -> Global Code Style -> General
```

- Disable the checkbox next to 'Use same settings for all file types'
- The 'XML' tab should become enabled. Click it and set the 'tab' (and probably 'indent') size to 2.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.3 it's 
File > Settings > Code Style > General

Answer (score 0):

Note: make sure to not use the *same* file in two project, or your settings might revert to the default (4 spaces), instead of the custom XML tab indent size.

See [bug IDEA-130878](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130878), for the latest IntelliJ IDEA 14 (Oct 2014)